# Hazelcast Out of memory issue

Tags: java, performance, configuration, out-of-memory, hazelcast

Frequent **out of memory** issue in **Hazelcast 3.3**, What I wonder is node has enough memory and CPU, 16GB Ram, 8 Core processor, still this error is happening. Its a **single node** setup.

```
com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastException: Client is shutting down!!!
    at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnection.innerClose(ClientConnection.java:302)
    at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnection.close(ClientConnection.java:355)
    at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnection.close(ClientConnection.java:230)
    at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl.shutdown(ClientConnectionManagerImpl.java:249)
    at com.hazelcast.client.ClientOutOfMemoryHandler$ClientHelper.closeSockets(ClientOutOfMemoryHandler.java:54)
    at com.hazelcast.client.ClientOutOfMemoryHandler$ClientHelper.cleanResources(ClientOutOfMemoryHandler.java:45)
    at com.hazelcast.client.ClientOutOfMemoryHandler.onOutOfMemory(ClientOutOfMemoryHandler.java:34)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.OutOfMemoryErrorDispatcher.onOutOfMemory(OutOfMemoryErrorDispatcher.java:143)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationService$OperationHandler.handleOperationError(BasicOperationService.java:827)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationService$OperationHandler.handle(BasicOperationService.java:703)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationService$OperationHandler.access$400(BasicOperationService.java:675)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationService.runOperationOnCallingThread(BasicOperationService.java:229)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocation.doInvokeLocal(BasicInvocation.java:286)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocation.doInvoke(BasicInvocation.java:272)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocation.invoke(BasicInvocation.java:232)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocationBuilder.invoke(BasicInvocationBuilder.java:45)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.client.PartitionClientRequest.process(PartitionClientRequest.java:60)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.ClientEngineImpl$ClientPacketProcessor.processRequest(ClientEngineImpl.java:418)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.ClientEngineImpl$ClientPacketProcessor.run(ClientEngineImpl.java:357)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationService$BasicDispatcherImpl.dispatch(BasicOperationService.java:546)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationScheduler$OperationThread.process(BasicOperationScheduler.java:439)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationScheduler$OperationThread.doRun(BasicOperationScheduler.java:433)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationScheduler$OperationThread.run(BasicOperationScheduler.java:408)
    at ------ End remote and begin local stack-trace ------.(Unknown Source)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientCallFuture.resolveResponse(ClientCallFuture.java:192)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientCallFuture.get(ClientCallFuture.java:134)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientCallFuture.get(ClientCallFuture.java:111)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:110)
    at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientMapProxy.get(ClientMapProxy.java:180)
```

For Every new run, this happens after (around) 15 mins of run.

After this, continuously We are getting the following error,

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Internal executor rejected task: java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@5463e258, because client is shutting down...
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientExecutionServiceImpl$1.rejectedExecution(ClientExecutionServiceImpl.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:821)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1372)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:110)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientExecutionServiceImpl.submitInternal(ClientExecutionServiceImpl.java:81)
    at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl.getOrConnect(ClientConnectionManagerImpl.java:339)
    at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl.tryToConnect(ClientConnectionManagerImpl.java:280)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationServiceImpl.send(ClientInvocationServiceImpl.java:120)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationServiceImpl.invokeOnRandomTarget(ClientInvocationServiceImpl.java:61)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.ProxyManager.initialize(ProxyManager.java:197)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.ProxyManager.getOrCreateProxy(ProxyManager.java:180)
    at com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClient.getDistributedObject(HazelcastClient.java:461)
    at com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClient.getMap(HazelcastClient.java:314)
    at com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClientProxy.getMap(HazelcastClientProxy.java:97)
```

Please, If there any configuration set up I need to add???

For **INFO**:

There is **no eviction policy** added, Its default as NONE.
Am using the **MAP STORE** for persistence policy with write delay as 1 second.

Comment: If anybody needs any more info, I will provide you in a minute... please do respond me...

Comment: Look for answers to the question "how do I find a memory leak in Java?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't have a support contract, this is a best value answer.

1. You have a single node setup, as wrong as a single node cluster sounds, as wrong it is to run Hazelcast that way. Hazelcast is not designed for single member clusters (and it doesn't make sense either).
2. The amount of heap is set to 16GB. What is your expected data value? I mean you cannot store 16GB of data in 16GB heap.
3. Have you tried to get a heap-dump when your JVM ran OOME? Have you looked into it to see what is eating up your memory? (as mentioned look for "how to find memory leaks")
4. If you have no eviction selected, you won't get eviction, even with a MapStore.
5. Have you tried different GC combinations or tried to look at the GC at all? There are different kinds of GC errors.
6. It seems like your client is running OOME so maybe the problem is not the amount of data at all. But since there is no further information, it is hard to reason.

Comment: Thanks Noctarius, but our total datas are in just few mbs, not even can cross 1gb. There is no problem in the memory of node, but When I look into the jvisual vm, the thread is increasing continously... In one point hazelcast just gets bursted... As you suggested, I will look into the heap dump too..

Comment: As of single node is concerned, what is the memory or performance configuration necessary for hazelcast... For info: as of machine is concerned all the configurations are pretty good like unlimit for user, process are all huge... So pls suggest me the memory or performance configuration for hazelcast

Comment: Well the thing that irritates me is, it seems like your client is shutting down because of ... well probably an OOME. The clients do not store data at all. If the client is killed by an OOME it is likely that your application has a memory leak. If the cluster node dies than for 1GB of data 4-5 GB of heap should be more than enough. The thing is, how do you make sure it is in the 1GB region? I saw a lot of customers in the past where objects grew way bigger than they expected.